# Inkscape leaving grey borders during SVG->PNG conversion

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, inkscape

We have a system that compiles SVGs from paths, textPaths, and uploaded images (.png being one supported type).

We then convert the .svg -> .png.  This process is leaving a strange grey border around images (and all transparent edges) as outlined in the image below.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's the conversion in Inkscape that's the problem, rather than the point when you're compositing? Can you add some details how you're compositing in your post? For the sake of detail, it might be worth adding in your Inkscape CLI parameters as well.

Comment: Also, if you can put your SVG document someplace, someone (perhaps me!) will run it through Inkscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible lucky guess, but I know that CI has some problems alpha transparency that can cause problems with transparent images. I had similar one with resizing of transparent PNGs.

Try to set Aplha to zero (I think this was proper solution)